Can't find androidx.appcompat
I want to start android development. As Android Studio is hungry for memory, I don't want to use Android Studio. I built a maven project and tried to add androidx library to my project. I spent the whole day but couldn't solve the error. I got only 6/7 packages from androidx. But I cannot find appcompat in androidx library. How can I add androidx properly in my project so that I can use appcompat?


Hope this link helps , https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat/1.7.0

As you can see from the link Swagat posted you need to include the maven Google repo   https://maven.google.com/ as repository. However your screenshot is strange - it is from a Maven project, Android usually uses Gradle for building. Make sure you don't use a tutorial or project that was designed for Eclipse + Development tools. These old tools aren't supported anymore.
